# Why pd.reset_index converts Series into DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have following data:

[image]

Next I perform:

[image]

What confuse me is the reset_index() changes the Series into DataFrame.
Why is that?
After seeing the pandas documentation, I expected an error, since reset_index is only applicable for DataFrame:

[image]

Thank you in advance for clearing that up for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [`Series Docs`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_pandas/python_pandas_series.htm):

> Series is a one-dimensional labeled array capable of holding data of any type.

When you do a `reset_index()`, another column is added to it, so it no more remains a `one-dimensional` Series, it becomes a `dataframe`.

From [`reset_index docs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

> Generate a new DataFrame or Series with the index reset.

Hope this clears your doubt a bit.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `Series.reset_index`.
So the right page to check is:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html

Answer (score 2):

The help for `Series.reset_index` is

```
reset_index(self, level=None, drop=False, name=None, inplace=False)
    Generate a new DataFrame or Series with the index reset.
    
    This is useful when the index needs to be treated as a column, or
    when the index is meaningless and needs to be reset to the default
    before another operation.

    ...
```

And the doc for `drop` is

```
    drop : bool, default False
        Just reset the index, without inserting it as a column in
        the new DataFrame.
```

By default the series is converted to a dataframe with a new index. But with `drop=False`, a series with a reset index is returned. That seems backwards to me - the default resetting the series index would be the more natural result of a thing called "reset_index" IMHO.